# JSF/Primefaces: GIF animation freezes when the backend bean thread is in sleep state

Tags: jquery, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am trying pause a transaction triggered by a JSF/primeface UI by placing the following code snipped in the function within a managed bean. When the user clicks the submit button, it triggers a function which contains the below sleep statement and after waking up the function performs several other stuff:

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        LOG.error(e1.getMessage());
    }
```

But the above sleep statement freezes the frontend GIF animation. My intention for pausing through the mbeans was to achieve a good user perceived performance when the program is trying to avoid few backend race conditions.

How to make sure that the browser thread does not get paused when the backend thread is in sleep mode?

Here is the global ajaxstatus tag I am using from primefaces framework:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
                onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />

            <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="false" draggable="false"
                closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
                <h:graphicImage value="resources/customimages/loading_mini.gif" />
            </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Are 100% sure this is actually happening? And not that by accident the image is not fully loaded or something like that? Or try instead of one sleep of 3000, you do 3000 sleeps of 1

Comment: I am sure the image is fully loaded, because the same image works in all other screens in the application except for the one posted in the question.

Comment: I also tried sleeping in smaller amounts, there is no effect on that in the UI. The primefaces framework is probably not doing asynchronous status checks from the browser. My theory is that the problem is with the browser thread waiting for the server to respond and if the server take a long time to respond then the client thread which is listening on the response will get locked till the response completes. Instead of animating the gif the thread is now busy waiting for the response.

Comment: PrimeFaces does do any 'check', synchronous or asynchronous (besides a normal ajax call) but what surprises me is that a blocking server thread or actually busy server thread makes diiference.

Comment: Did you try different browsers? And did you search in general for browser freeze spinner or something similar?